# network device module equivalent to ping

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have made a module which is transmitting but I don't know whether the packet which I am transmitting is a ping packet or not. Code is shown below:

```c
 icmp.type = 8;
 icmp.code = 0;
 icmp.un.echo.sequence = i;
 ip4.protocol = 1; //for icmp protocol
 ip4.frag_off = 0;
 ip4.daddr = in_aton(procfs_buffer);
 ip4.saddr = in_aton(ifr->ifr_addr.sa_data);

 len = sizeof(data);

 skb = dev_alloc_skb(1500);
 skb->dev = __dev_get_by_name(&init_net,"wlan0");
 skb_reserve(skb,NET_IP_ALIGN); // header of 2 bytes; increments tail and 
                                // data pointer
 skb->data = skb_put(skb,sizeof(len)); // increments all pointer or adds data
 memcpy(data,skb->data,len);

 skb->transport_header =skb_push(skb,sizeof(icmp));
 memset(skb->transport_header,0,sizeof(struct icmphdr));
 memcpy(skb->transport_header,&icmp,sizeof(struct icmphdr));

 skb->network_header=skb_push(skb,sizeof(ip4));
 memset(skb->network_header,0,sizeof(struct iphdr));
 memcpy(skb->network_header,&ip4,sizeof(struct iphdr));

 // printk("i::%d\n",i);
 // skb->mac_header = skb_push(skb,6*sizeof(0xFF));
 // memset(skb->mac_header,0xFF,6*sizeof(0xFF));
 dev_queue_xmit(skb);
 kfree(skb);
```

How can I know that it is a ping packet which I am creating and transmitting?  Further I want to receieve the ping packet in response to my ping packet which I have transmitted. I would like to use napi but wont mind any other suggestions.

please read a topic : reception napi mode [here](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~nahum/w6998/lectures/device-layer.ppt) i could nt understand what to do from the link above.....

Comment: You made a kernel module but you don't know what it does ... ?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I know whats its doing (at this point its only transmitting) but I am not sure whether its transmitting a ping packet or not and dont know how to recieve packets and check whether they are ping response from other side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a `ping` packet is simply icmp packet with code 8, with timestamp in its data
icmp echo reply (ping reply) just copies the data from the icmp echo request and sends it back, this way ping can tell you how much time it took for the round trip (now - prev' sended time)

i am not very familiar with the linux kernel, but be sure to calculate the correct ip and icmp checksums

also for receiving, it might be better to use netfilter

Comment: could you please tell me how to calculate checksums or are theirany functions provided by the kernel to calculaten it.....

Comment: @karan421 take a look at `icmp_push_reply()` called from `icmp_reply()` inside `net/ipv4/icmp.c`, like i said, i am not familiar with the linux kernel

Answer (score 1):

You can use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to capture all network traffic going in and out of one of your network interface. You'll be able to check that the packet has been sent and if it was actually what you expect it to be. You'll also be able to see if there is an answer to your ping.

Regarding your question on how to intercept the ping answer from your module, you can use the netfilter API offered by the kernel. [Here is](http://www.paulkiddie.com/2009/11/creating-a-netfilter-kernel-module-which-filters-udp-packets/) a good article to start with using netfilter.